# Was Eli the Priest considered righteous

Tags: talmud-gemara

How is Eli the high priest depicted In rabbinic sources.  Though he sinned he seemed to be a righteous man who loved God but faced tbe consequences of his sin

Answer (score 1):

Where do you find that he sinned? At most he sinned by not rebuking his sons for their misdeeds (which were, according to our Sages, also not the way it sounds from the Psukim) or, as the Sefer Chasidim (5757) writes by allowing them to stay in their jobs https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14561&st=&pgnum=173 & https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14561&st=&pgnum=174.
He was considered a great Tzaddik. The punishment to his family came because of his sons.